# Left outer join with right table filter

Tags: sql-server, filter, left-join

I have two tables:

Shipping

```
ShippedItem Returned
----------- --------
A           NULL
B           NULL
C           NULL
D           Yes
E           Yes
```

Return

```
ReturnItem Reason
---------- --------------------
D          Not Good
E          Defect
```

I need to write a query which will give Shipping qty and return Qty (Return qty ie..where return is not null) basing on Return reason.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ca035)

Comment: What would be your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but here are a few notes about your question.

You can't return shipping qty nor return qty because your tables don't have those fields. That was probably just an oversight on your part and those tables do have those fields.

You said you want a right table filter but you don't mention what that filter is.

You mention a left outer join so presumably you know how to write one.

If I had to guess what your question is, I would say that you want to filter something on the Return table but still get all the rows from the Shipping table that are not in the Return table.

If so, what you do is move your right table filter from the WHERE clause into the JOIN clause.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Shipping
    LEFT JOIN Returns
    ON ShippedItem = ReturnItem
    AND Returns.otherField = Filter here
```